# Why $A$-invariant condition implies an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am following the method of using the homogeneous components to find the eigenvectors related to general molecular vibration problem using the symmetry group $G$ in this book by James and Liebeck titled Representations and Characters of Groups.

Suppose we want to find the vibration modes of an $n$ atom molecule. The equation of motion is given by $\ddot x=xA$. Here $x$ is the row vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$. Suppose that $\chi$ is the character of an irreducible $\mathbb{R}G$-module. Let $V_{\chi}$ denote the sum of those $\mathbb{R}G$ submodules of $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$ which have character $\chi$. We call $V_{\chi}$ a homogeneous component of $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$ which is also $A$-invariant because $$ xA \in V_{\chi} $$for all $$x \in V_{\chi} $$

Now on page 377 we have this corollary and its proof:

If $V_{\chi}$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{R}G$-module, then all the non-zero vectros in $V_{\chi}$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Proof:

Since $V_{\chi}$ is $A$-invariant, we may choose $v \in V_{\chi}$ such that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then the intersection of $V_{\chi}$ with the eigenspace for $\lambda$ is a non-zero $\mathbb{R}G$-submodule of $V_{\chi}$, so it must equal $V_{\chi}$.

My question is that why

***Since $V_{\chi}$ is $A$-invariant, we may choose $v \in V_{\chi}$ such that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$***

I see that there are eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$ but why $A$-invariant condition does imply the existence of an eigenvector in $V_{\chi}$?

Schur's lemma says for an irreducible $\mathbb{C}G$-module $V$ the action of $A$ should be a scalar multiple of the identity endomorphism, that is $A=\lambda I$  with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

But here $V_{\chi}$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{R}G$-module not an irreducible $\mathbb{C}G$-module.

Comment: Could you please give more context for those who don't have the book? Especially about the notations and hypothesis.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks. Just added a few more lines for more context. Is it enough?

Comment: It's better, but there's still one thing I don't really get. What is the relation between $G$ and $A$ here? There must be something, but I don't get it (maybe be $A$ commutes with the action of $G$?). Sorry if it seems obvious to you, I don't know much about applications of representation theory to that sort of problems.

Comment: @ArnaudD. you are right, they commute, but is this related to the question above?

Comment: Maybe. When you say "I see that there are eigenvectors in $$\Bbb R^{3n}$", do you mean that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I added Schur's lemma to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assumption of their model is that $A$ acts diagonalizably on $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$, which is spelled out in Proposition 32.7. This means $A$ acts diagonalizably on any $A$-invariant subspace (its minimum polynomial $m$ on the whole space is a product of distinct linear factors, its restriction to a subspace also satisfies $m$, so the min poly of the restriction divides $m$ and hence is itself a product of distinct linear factors).  If it acts diagonalizably on a nonzero space, it has eigenvectors.